# How it works with a QVector<QVector<float_t>>. What is the optimized way?

Tags: c++, arrays, dataframe, qt5, qvector

I am working with Qt C++, am trying to use **QVector** to store data from a file of **4 interleaved channels**, and use it afterwords.
I tried something like that but still not sure how to store every channel data in a different vector(column),

```
QVector<QVector<float_t> > buffer(4);

for(int i = 0; i < 10000 < i++){
QByteArray tmp = file.read(3); // 24 bits for each channel
float x = my_converison_that_works(tmp); 
buffer.append(x);
}
```

I am looking for an optimized way for this task, any help!

Comment: what is `x` ? I read the comment but that confused me even more

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do or what is the problem you have with your code. What exactly do you mean with "to store data from a file of 4 interleaved channels, and use it afterwords." ?

Comment: not clear still. `// x = conversion from tmp to x ` how do you want that conversion to happen? Its not obvious how a `QVector<float_t>` should be constructed from a `QByteArray`. If you don't know how you want that to happen, how should others know?

Comment: x is a conversion to float from tmp. What I mean the file has the data of 4 interleaved channels(file: data_ch1 data_ch2 data_ch3 data_ch4 data_ch1 data_ch_2 ... ) it is storing several channels in a single file.

Comment: you should edit the question to clarify details. It all depends what is stored in the file and what you want to do with the data from the file

Comment: the conversion is another function which i have no problem with, the file I read from has QBytearray hexadicimal data and I want to store the float(the float data I have and I did the conversion I need) data in QVector<QVector<float>>, just wondering how to store 4 columns of float data in a QVector of Qvectors.

Comment: Are you reading some image data, for example some video frame in raw format?

Comment: it is audio data

Comment: In the code you posted it looks like that is the missing part. I mean you could just make it `float x = my_converison_that_works(tmp);`. (you will still get requests to show the implemenation probably, but it would be a little less confusing)

Comment: okay now ```float x = my_converison_that_works(tmp);``` is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have each channel in a speperate `QVector` then just append each channel to a different `QVector`:

```
QVector<QVector<float_t> > buffer(4);

for(int i = 0; i < 10000 < i++){

    for (auto& channel : buffer) {
        QByteArray tmp = file.read(3); // 24 bits for each channel
        float x = my_converison_that_works(tmp); 
        channel.append(x);
    } 
}
```

Your code appends a single `float` to the buffer. That wont work. You do not want to append to `buffer` but to `buffer[0]`,`buffer[1]`,..., (`channel` in above code).

For "the optimal" you should reserve space in the vectors before appending to them. Alternatively use a container with fixed size, when you know the size at compile time.

Comment: I like the range based for loop as well: `for(...) { for(auto& channel : buffer) { float x = ...; channel.append(x); } }`

Comment: @Aconcagua good point, though for illustration I prefer a named index `channel`

Comment: Could still edit, renamed the loop variable accordingly ;)

Comment: Thanks, now I understand a bit how it works with vectors of vectors, I will give it a try ;)